# Database user with dbAdmin role can't eval

Tags: mongodb

My databases have their own users set, and now I want to eval certain functions, like:

```
function() {
    db.mydatabase.ensureIndex(<fields>, <options>);
}
```

But that never works, I get an **unauthorized** error.

But the user IS authorized and authenticated. If now, I wouldn't be able to connect.
The user also has the dbAdmin role set, which I thought was needed for version 2.4 and up.

I tried to login using an admin user,  but that doesn't work unless you log into the admin database itself.

This is the user of 'mydatabase':

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("534290d2bfeb13f0b91d52d3"),
    "user" : "myuser",
    "pwd" : "blabla",
    "roles" : [ 
        "read", 
        "readWrite", 
        "dbAdmin", 
        "userAdmin", 
        "clusterAdmin", 
        "readAnyDatabase", 
        "readWriteAnyDatabase", 
        "userAdminAnyDatabase", 
        "dbAdminAnyDatabase"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The concept of where you can use **`eval`** in your programming is very much covered both [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/eval/) and importantly [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#noscripting).

The short points are:

- You need special permissions in order to be able to use the command, as well as take into consideration that you cannot do this on sharded clusters.
- From the second link this can be explicitly disabled on the instance startup. So it is probably good practice of hosting providers to do this by default in their setup.

While [**`eval`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/eval/) does have some valid usages in a "get out of jail" sense to solve specific "one-off" problems when altering collection formats, the general usage in production environments should be discouraged.

As the **second** link suggests, search for other alternatives to using the **eval** form when running in production environments. There are serious problems around the corner if you persist in actually doing this.